# XamlParseException on window initialization

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

I am getting this error when I go to open my WPF window and I have no idea what created the error or how to get rid of it. The error is highlighting and pointing to `</Border>` at the bottom.

```
'Initialization of 'Outlook_Add_In_Test.WPFExiEvent' threw an exception.' Line number '91' and line position '11'.
```

My WPF Code:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="Outlook_Add_In_Test.WPFExiEvent"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
             xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="550" MaxHeight="640" MaxWidth="550" Title="Search for an Existing Event" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Height="340" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">

    <Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colours.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/Test.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/FlatButton.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>

    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,-1">


            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="1" Margin="6,108,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="524" Opacity="0.2" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Border.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Border.RenderTransform>
            </Border>

            <Image x:Name="ImgDefactoLogo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="36" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="43" Source="Images/DeFactoERP.ico"/>
            <Image x:Name="ImgAttachmentType" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="65,10,0,0" Width="32" RenderTransformOrigin="0.143,0.778" Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <Label Content="Search for an Existing Event" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="36" Margin="97,19,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="259" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="LblInfo"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="47" Margin="10,60,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="524" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Arial" Text="Please search for an existing event in your De Facto ERP system that you want to use for adding the attachment to."/>
            <Label Content="Event No:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="43" Margin="7,126,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="112" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black"/>
            <Label Content="Event Subject:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="43" Margin="7,164,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="119" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="TxtEventNo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="33" Margin="151,126,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" ToolTip="Enter Event Number..." KeyDown="TxtEventNo_KeyDown" TextChanged="TxtEventNo_TextChanged"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="TxtSubject" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="33" Margin="151,164,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" KeyDown="TxtSubject_KeyDown" TextChanged="TxtSubject_TextChanged"/>
            <Label Content="Event Customer:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="43" Margin="7,202,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="142" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="TxtCust" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="33" Margin="342,22,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" ToolTip="Enter Event Number..." TextChanged="TxtCust_TextChanged" KeyDown="TxtCust_KeyDown"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="ChkActive" Content="Active Events Only" IsChecked="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19" Margin="13,238,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="124" Checked="ChkActive_Checked" Unchecked="ChkActive_UnChecked"/>

            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="1" Margin="7,267,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="524" Opacity="0.2" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Border.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Border.RenderTransform>
            </Border>

            <Button x:Name="BtnSearch" Click="BtnSearch_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100" Background="#FF333333" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="14" Margin="422,162,0,0" Height="37" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <TextBlock Text="SEARCH" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Right" FontSize="14" Width="73" Height="15" FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="White" RenderTransformOrigin="0.684,0.261"/>
            </Button>

            <ListBox x:Name="LstEvents" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,300,0,14" Width="524" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2,2,1,1">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Height="97">
                            <Canvas x:Name="EventItem" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="97" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="502" Background="{Binding LBackground}" Margin="0,0,0,-21">
                                <Label Content="Event:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="33" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="97" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Canvas.Left="1" Canvas.Top="2"/>
                                <Label Content="Subject:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="33" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="97" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Canvas.Left="1" Canvas.Top="23"/>
                                <Label Content="Body:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="33" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="97" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Canvas.Left="1" Canvas.Top="47"/>
                                <Button x:Name="BtnSelectEvent" Content="Select" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74" Background="#FF333333" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="14" Canvas.Left="418" Canvas.Top="33" Click="BtnSelectEvent_Click"/>
                                <Label Content="{Binding Lsubject}" Height="25" Canvas.Left="80" Canvas.Top="3" Width="333"/>
                                <Label Content="{Binding Lbody}" Height="25" Canvas.Left="80" Canvas.Top="25" Width="333"/>
                                <Label Content="{Binding Lbody}" Height="25" Canvas.Left="80" Canvas.Top="49" Width="333"/>
                                <Label Content="Customer:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="33" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="97" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Canvas.Left="1" Canvas.Top="69"/>
                                <Label Content="{Binding LCust}" Height="25" Canvas.Left="80" Canvas.Top="71" Width="333"/>
                            </Canvas>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>

            <Label x:Name="LblResultsReturned" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="37,273,0,-19" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="492" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="11" />
            <Label x:Name="LblEventCount" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="10,273,0,-19" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="11" />
            <Image x:Name="ImgSearch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="431,171,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="22" Source="Images/Icon-Search-Big-White.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.419,1.269"/>
            <Label x:Name="LblError" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="199,273,0,-19" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="330" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="11" />
            <Controls:ProgressRing x:Name="LoadingRing" IsActive="False" Margin="356,153,126,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </Grid>
   </Border>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

Comment: Read the InnerException.

Comment: {"The type initializer for 'MahApps.Metro.Behaviours.StylizedBehaviors' threw an exception."}

Comment: Then there is a problem in the static constructor of StylizedBehaviors

Comment: Read the Inner InnerException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going on what you said in the comments it seems it is linked to the MahApps Metro Theme.

Take a look at this: https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/582

If you have referenced the Windows Interactivity dll try removing it.

In future remember to check the InnerException like SLaks said. You can learn a lot more from this and give you more to work on.

Comment: Thank you. Removing it did work however some of my newer stuff has stopped working. I will take a deeper look into it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe for someone it will be useful. Today I ran into the same problem:

"XamlParseException on window initialization" in project with nuget reference to MahApp.
I tryed reinstaling packages, removing references - nothithing helped.

In may case the problem was in app.config. When I removed these lines, problem disappeared:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Windows.Interactivity" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="4.5.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just imported the wrong dll (NET40). Try to import the latest MahApps.Metro.dll (NET45).

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I downgraded the MahApps.Metro to version 1.6.4 and the error has gone
I was using version 1.6.5 before

And the version of MahApps.Metro.Resources is 0.6.1